# cordova build undo my custom code

Tags: cordova, cordova-3

i have created a simple project using cordova-3.4.0.

The default code is deploying and running fine in mobile.

But if i am updating any code on

> HTML, CSS, JS

it will undo my updated code, and running with default code only.

I am using the following command for compile

```
root/> cordova build android
```

to run

```
root/> cordova run android
```

Any help. Please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was editing files inside

```
projectroot/platform/android/assets/www/
```

instead of

```
projectroot/www/
```

Now its working fine.